# Do I need a new key when updating my iOS app with a completely new binary from PhoneGap?

Tags: ios, mobile, certificate, publish, phonegap-build

My company is looking into using PhoneGap to build our iOS app. We already have an app on the app store, built with Xcode and Objective-C.

We want to replace our old app with the new PhoneGap app (so it will have the same Apple ID and bundle ID), but I am unclear on what I need as far as new certificates/keys. Can we use the certificates from the old app with the new? What new certificates would we need to get, if any?

I've read up on getting a new key for PhoneGap, so if I need to do that, that's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a provisioning profile for distribution. You can use the same one unless it's expired.

Comment: That's good news. What about the certificate itself (the p12 file)?

Comment: That stays the same too.